# Find max values in arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, max

I have a txt file I put into an array. The data in the txt file has data in the format as:

```
Order #     Date     Name     City     State    Zip Code    Transaction Amount
```

across a row with each item representing a column.

Then there is a 1000 more rows that have these filled in with answers. I need help with finding the top 3 amounts from the transaction amounts. Am stuck on how to do this. When I run the program, it only prints out Order #, Date, etc. instead of the account with the highest amount.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rewards {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

FileReader fin = new FileReader(
        "C:/Users/Jordan/Desktop/Project5Text.txt");
Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

Random rand = new Random();

while (src.hasNext()) {
    String l = src.nextLine();
    System.out.println(l);
    if (!l.equals(""))
        lines.add(l);

}

System.out.println();

String[] randomChoices = new String[1];

for (int i = 0; i < randomChoices.length; i++) {
    String randomString = lines.get(1 + rand.nextInt(lines.size() - 1));
    randomChoices[i] = randomString;
}

for (String s : randomChoices)
    System.out.println("Random Winner for $20 gift card is:       " + s);

String[] randomChoices1 = new String[1];

for (int i = 0; i < randomChoices1.length; i++) {
    String randomString = lines.get(1 + rand.nextInt(lines.size() - 1));
    randomChoices1[i] = randomString;
}

for (String s : randomChoices1)
    System.out.println("Random Winner for $40 gift card is:       " + s);

String[] randomChoices2 = new String[1];

for (int i = 0; i < randomChoices2.length; i++) {
    String randomString = lines.get(1 + rand.nextInt(lines.size() - 1));
    randomChoices2[i] = randomString;
}

for (String s : randomChoices2)
    System.out.println("Random Winner for $60 gift card is:       " + s);

String[] randomChoices3 = new String[1];

for (int i = 0; i < randomChoices3.length; i++) {
    String randomString = lines.get(1 + rand.nextInt(lines.size() - 1));
    randomChoices3[i] = randomString;
}

for (String s : randomChoices3)
    System.out.println("Random Winner for $80 gift card is:       " + s);

String[] randomChoices4 = new String[1];

for (int i = 0; i < randomChoices4.length; i++) {
    String randomString = lines.get(1 + rand.nextInt(lines.size() - 1));
    randomChoices4[i] = randomString;
}

for (String s : randomChoices4)
        System.out.println("Random Winner for $100 gift card is:      " + s);

    Object obj = Collections.max(lines);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Highest Transaction Amount is:");
    System.out.println(obj);

    src.close();
}
}
```

Here is some of the text file I am using.

```
Order # Date First name Middle Initial Last name Address City State Zip Email Transaction Amount

1 8/26/2012 Kristina H Chung 947 Martin Ave. Muncie CA 46489 khchung@business.com $593

2 11/16/2012 Paige H Chen 15 MainWay Rd. Dallas HI 47281 phchen@business.com $516

3 11/10/2012 Sherri E Melton 808 Washington Way Brazil CA 47880 semelton@business.com $80

4 9/20/2012 Gretchen I Hill 56 Washington Dr. Atlanta FL 47215 gihill@business.com $989

5 3/11/2012 Karen U Puckett 652 Maplewood Ct. Brazil FL 46627 kupuckett@business.com $826

6 7/4/2012 Patrick O Song 679 MainWay Rd. Lafayette GA 47161 posong@business.com $652
```

Answer (score 0):

What the line

```
Object obj = Collections.max(lines);
```

does is only to sort all the lines alphabetically. This is because `lines` is an `ArrayList` of `String`s and what `Collections.max` does is to sort a collections based on its natural ordering and retrieving the highest line in alphabetical order.

You need to parse the transaction amount from each line and add each value into an array of `Integer`s (or `Double`s, depending on your specific needs).

I would replace

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

while (src.hasNext()) {
    String l = src.nextLine();
    System.out.println(l);
    if (!l.equals(""))
        lines.add(l);
}
```

with

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> amounts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (src.hasNext()) {
    String l = src.nextLine();
    System.out.println(l);
    if (!l.equals("")){
        lines.add(l);
        String amount = l.substring(l.lastIndexOf('$') + 1);
        amounts.add(Integer.parseInt(amount));
    }
}
```

As well, the final lines would be:

```
Integer amount= Collections.max(amounts);

System.out.println();
System.out.println("Highest Transaction Amount is:");
System.out.println(amount);
```